# Length property in SP list

Tags: 2013

When i loop in a SP list with several items and use property length does the length property get only the longest item from the list or does it get length of all items?
my code:

```
var maxLength = 0;
var longestListTitle = "";
var Enum = list.getEnumerator();
while (Enum.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
    var listTitle = currentItem.get_title();
    if (listTitle.length > maxLength) {
        longestListTitle = listTitle;
        maxLength = longestListTitle.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what list was initialized as, it could be a collection of lists or a collection of lit items. What that is will determine what is being returned, it is either the longest list name or the longest item title in a list.

Comment: It is longest list name. Ok I got it now. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you shared `listTitle.length` will give you the no of characters in the value of `listTitle` variable.

For eg:

```
var listTitle="Sample";
console.log(listTitle.length);//output=6
```

Comment: OK but if I have several items it will pick the longest ?

Comment: Yes your code looks okay.It would give you the longest title